# Quarkus : Mock bean in dev mode

Tags: java, quarkus, dev-mode, quarkus-grpc

In my Quarkus application have a bean with a grpc client :

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Slf4j
public class AuthorizationAdapter implements AuthorizationPort {

    private final AuthorizationGrpc.AuthorizationBlockingStub authorizationBlockingStub;

    public AuthorizationAdapter(
            @GrpcClient("authorization") AuthorizationGrpc.AuthorizationBlockingStub authorizationBlockingStub) {
        this.authorizationBlockingStub = authorizationBlockingStub;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canActorReadReport(Actor actor, UUID reportId) {
        ... call authorizationBlockingStub here

    }
}
```

For test i managed to mock this bean with  :

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Mock
public class MockAuthorizationAdapter implements AuthorizationPort {

    @Override
    public boolean canActorReadReport(Actor actor, UUID reportId) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But in dev mode i want to do the same (i don't have and want to start a grpc server).
How can i do ?
I am aware that i could annotate this bean with @IfBuildProfile("prod") and create another one mocked but it would pollute my src/main/java and i don't want that.
Is it possible to achieve this in an elegant way ?

Comment: There is no easy to do this without a custom extension

Comment: Custom extension that does what ?

Comment: That generated a mock bean for dev-mode only

Comment: Ok will try but i have never done an extension before -_-